# Чем отличаются parseInt и Math.floor?

Tags: javascript

Вроде бы эти две функции работают одинаково:

```js
console.log(Math.floor(3.05));
console.log(parseInt(3.05));
```

Есть ли какие-то отличия?

Comment: Они работают очень сильно по-разному. `parseInt` сперва преобразует полученный аргумент в строку, а потом пытается распарсить строку обратно в число. Попробуйте например число `9e307` — результаты будут отличаться

Comment: @andreymal попробовала, при использовании `Math.floor` появляется непонятный плюс. [Например](https://jsfiddle.net/Lypr1ozg/) Почему он появляется?

Answer (score 1):

Разница в их назначении.

[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> Функция parseInt() принимает **строку** в качестве аргумента и возвращает
> целое число в соответствии с указанным основанием системы счисления.
>
> Если значение параметра string не принадлежит строковому типу, оно
> преобразуется в него

[Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

> Метод Math.floor() - округление вниз. Округляет аргумент до ближайшего
> меньшего целого.

Округление числа и парсинг строки для получения целого числа - это разные вещи.

Comment: А ещё они дадут разный результат на отрицательных числах

Comment: Ну что касается преобразования в строку... то я думаю, что `Math.floor` также преобразует из строки в число полученный аргумент. [Вот например](https://jsfiddle.net/3b1je6g5/2/)

Comment: @Eva , parseInt() , если написать в него число, будет его преобразовывать в строку перед работой, и только потом эту строку парсить в число. Он не просто входящее число округлит. Получается лишняя работа. А вы говорите про входящую строку. Да, она для Math.floor будет становиться числом перед округлением, но у parseInt() входящая строка не будет преобразовываться в число перед работой, потому что там ожидается строка на входе.

Comment: @PavelGrishaev, _у parseInt() входящая строка не будет преобразовываться в число перед работой, потому что там ожидается строка на входе._ - эта строка преобразуется в число в процессе работы